# Apache tries to redirect to an 'index.html' folder?

Tags: configuration, virtualhost, apache2

I have a strange behaviour I can't explain. Obviously some misconfiguration. I have in all two domains, the first domain has a lot of subdomains and works well. But my second domain, let's say `www.mydomain.cooking` (that's a valid TLD), does some weird redirects. When I enter `www.mydomain.cooking/index.html` into the URL bar, everything works as expected. But when I enter `www.mydomain.cooking`, it tries to redirect to an non existing index.html **folder**, so the domain looks like this after redirection `www.mydomain.cooking/index.html/`. How does this redirect come? I have exactly the same `VirtualHost` entries for all the working subdomains as for the second main domain. And I don't see such behaviour on the subdomains of the first domain.
This is the VirtualHost config of the second domain with the strange redirects:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName www.mydomain.cooking
        DocumentRoot /var/domains/www.mydomain.cooking

        <Directory /var/domains/www.mydomain.cooking/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas?

**[UPDATE]**
Today, I suddenly worked without doing anything special. Very strange. I will keep an eye on it. I hope, that this was just some caching issue or something.

Comment: Have you tried `<Directory "/var/domains/www.mydomain.cooking">` without the trailing slash?  What do the logs tell you? Have you reloaded apache?

Comment: No difference, no error in log, and yes, reloaded it.